# Testing spring-boot @service class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-test

I want to test a `@Service` class that is normally called with `SpringApplication.run()`.

The service class is:

```
@Service
@EnableConfigurationProperties(AppProperties.class)
public class MongoService {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MongoService.class);

    private MongoClient mongoClient;

    private final AppProperties properties;

    @Autowired
    public MongoService(AppProperties properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    /**
     * Open connection
     */
    public void openConnection() {

        try {
            mongoClient = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI(properties.getMongoConnectionString()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Cannot create connection to Search&Browse database", e);
            throw new BackendException("Cannot create connection to Search&Browse database");
        }
    }

}
```

When it is called by the controller started with `SpringApplication.run()`, the `MongoService` is not null but, when I try from a jUnit it's not working.

So, I'm trying this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppProperties.class)
public class MongoServiceTest {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MongoServiceTest.class);

    @Autowired
    MongoService mongoService;

    @Test
    public void MongoServiceAutowired() {   
        assertNotNull(mongoService);
    }
}
```

but I'm getting this exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'mypackage.MongoServiceTest':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mongoService'; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'mypackage.services.mongo.MongoService'
>   available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Any clue? Where am I failing?

Comment: `@SpringBootTest` is looking for a `@SpringBootApplication`, which needs to be at the root level of your project (because it searches for Spring 
components/configurations recursively) [or otherwise specify where to look for stuff via `@ComponentScan`]. Is this the case?

Comment: I have added the @ComponentScan but without success (jUnits are stored on /test folder)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume that your `AppProperties` and `MongoService` is not in the same package

If not you can inject `MongoService` in that way :

create another class named `TestConfiguration`

```
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {
        MongoService.class,
        AppProperties.class
})
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestConfiguration {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestConfiguration.class, args);
    }
}
```

And in the test just change to :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestConfiguration.class) 
public class MongoServiceTest {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MongoServiceTest.class);

    @Autowired
    MongoService mongoService;

    @Test
    public void MongoServiceAutowired() {   
        assertNotNull(mongoService);
    }
}
```